# Need guidance with SEO friendly URLS via mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I've been having a hard time getting this to actually work. So I'm using a CMS that through its own administration tools utilizes "pretty urls" so the `.htaccess` file that is generated comes pre-supplied with a Rewrite Condition already. Now this works but its only for the CMS generated pages that are extensions of the `index.php`. So for example `index.php?id=maps` are nicely shown as `www.siteurl.com/maps/` instead of `www.siteurl.com/index.php?id=maps`.

Now my problem is that I have about 1900+ product pages that are generated from query strings.

So for example I have page urls that look like:

```
https://www.siteurl.com/item.php?id=0012345&pg=author-title
```

ideally I want the urls to be:

```
https://www.siteurl.com/0012345/author-title.html
```

I've tried a number of mod_rewrite generators to give me the correct syntax, but nothing has worked so far.

Currently in my `.htaccess` file is the preexisting language:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I changed it to something like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /item.php?id=$1&pg=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But it doesn't work. I just get a `404` page. Please tell me where I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing /index.php with index.php.

What's kind of counter intuitive is that you need the leading slash in Apache server configuration, but must omit it in htaccess.

Comment: My problem is with the URLs after item.php. This page is what runs the query for each product. The query requires information from a GET for data in 'id' and 'pg'. I just need a way to clean up these URLs.